# Retrieve Azure Cloud Services information via api

Tags: azure

Im looking to retrieve information like Name, description of the Cloud Services being used in my azure cloud environment.
Im not talking about the specific information of an instance of a cloud service I have in my environment but the general types of cloud services that Azure provides, which can be found here for example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/?product=popular

For example: Azure Virtual Machines and the description of what that is as found on the website.

I already looked into the Azure Resource Graph api, but it seems I can only retrieve the resource type directly. Is there any way to retrieve this information?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloud-services/list-all?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) use `GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/cloudServices?api-version=2022-09-04` to retrieve Cloud Services Info.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct API to get all the available `Azure services` but as an alternative you can get the List of all Azure services eligible for creating Support request by using the  [Services - List - REST API (Azure Support)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/support/services/list?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0)

[image]

To List Azure Resources like Azure VM,App Service,Function App..
I have used the API mentioned in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list#code-try-0).

> ```cs
> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/YourSubscriptionID/resources?api-version=2021-04-01
> ```

[image]

***For Cloud Service Instance.***

I have created a `Cloud services (extended support).

- Refer the [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cloud-services-extended-support/tree/main/101-cses-multirole-wad) to upload `.cspkg`,`.cscfg`,`csdef` files.

[image]

[image]

I have followed the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloud-services/list-all?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) to retrieve the Cloud Services in my subscription.

> ```cs
> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubscriptionID/providers/Microsoft.Compute/cloudServices?api-version=2022-09-04
> ```

***Output:***

[image]